# How to turn off this graphic effect on The Outer Worlds?

Tags: pc, graphics-card, the-outer-worlds

The image looks disgusting, although the maximum graphics settings are set. Everything looks too soapy and blurry. It's like I'm looking through some very dirty glass.

[image: tow][image: tow]
[image: tow]

Comment: Um... I don't know how that game is supposed to look, but to me, those are some beautiful graphics. I don't see a problem here, at all.

Comment: I would check for settings such as chromatic aberration, blur, film grain, etc. and disable if possible.

Comment: @TheMattbat999 When I zoom in a bit, I can see some kind of blurry deformation around vegetation in particular. On the other hand, everything else seems fine. The effect seems exaggerated in the first picture, looking through the scope. Though this seems to be an side-effect from the grid-like effect in the crosshair section.

Comment: And to comment on the question - have you tried the various fixes found in [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/theouterworlds/comments/dmznq0/the_outer_worlds_looks_blurry_and_i_cant_get_it/)? They don't seem to be conclusive for the poster, but there's a bunch of `ini` fixes that turn of a variety of effects.

Comment: To me it seems like that's just how the game assets look..

Comment: Judging from exactly this [frame](https://youtu.be/B6sDv_iSBAc?t=7942) (pause exactly there) as well as the [launch trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oxlflrh_Pzw), that is just how the game is supposed to look. if you are unhappy with that, you will need to develop a graphics mod/update yourself

Comment: "Disgusting" is not a helpful adjective when talking about graphics settings.

Answer (score 5):

None of the posted images look off when compared to any and all released footage of the gameplay in online videos (both official trailers and let's plays).

I'm discounting the first image as the scopes specifically add an additional filter to the graphics, while also blowing up the resolution of the assets in view (and TOW does not improve texture quality when zooming in).

The Outer Worlds does not have the best textures ever seen (e.g. the glove in your third picture, various cases of pop-in), and the general graphic design leans towards the saturated/bright/blocky as opposed to hyperrealistic colors.
There is a generally yellow filter overlaid - at least in most outdoor places such as Monarch where your screenshots were taken.

Overall, I don't see an issue here. It seems like you simply don't like the general aesthetic that TOW has intentionally gone for.